# Delete lines from the form without updating the form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am deleting the lines of the form according to the database with an asynchronous request.
The problem is that whenever I delete lines, if I have made any changes to the form I lose all the changes because I make the request back to the database.

So I intend to remove the lines without having to make a request to the database.

Code:

```
success:function(data1){
var linha1 = ``;
for (var i = 0; i < data1.length; i++) { 
Id = data1[i][0];
DataRegisto = data1[i][1];
Cliente = data1[i][2];
Orcamento = data1[i][3];
Ref = data1[i][4];
Designacao = data1[i][5];
Quantidade = data1[i][6];
Valor = data1[i][7];
Compra = data1[i][8];
  
  linha1 += `<input type="checkbox" name="eliprod[]" class="rest" value="${ Id }">
  <input type="hidden" class="form-control1" name="Id[]" value="${Id}">
<div class="form-group col-md-2">  
  <input type="text" class="form-control1" name="Refe[]" value="${Ref}">
  <span class="form-highlight"></span>
  <span class="form-bar"></span>
  <label class="label1" for="Refe">Refª</label>        
  </div>
<div class="form-group col-md-10">  
  <input type="text" class="form-control1" name="Designaca[]" value="${Designacao}">
  <span class="form-highlight"></span>
  <span class="form-bar"></span>
  <label class="label1" for="Designaca">Designação</label>        
</div>`;
}
linha1 += `<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger caixa btn-show close-sidebar delete_prod"><i class="fa fa-trash fa-5x taman" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>`;
$("#retorc1").html(linha1);
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).on("click", ".delete_prod", function(){
 var eliprod = [];
   $("input[name='eliprod[]']").each(function() {eliprod.push(this.checked)});
   var Id = [];
   $("input[name='Id[]']").each(function() {Id.push(this.value)});
    var dadosajax = {
      'eliprod[]' : eliprod,
      'Id[]' : Id
    };
        
        if(confirm('Tem certeza de que deseja remover o produto do orçamento?'))
        {
            $.ajax({
               url: 'delorc.php',
               type: 'GET',
               cache: false,
               data: dadosajax,
               error: function() {
                  alert('Algo está errado!');
               },
               success: function(data) {
                   var orc = $("input[name='orc']").val();

                   $.getJSON('updorc2.php?orc'+ '&orc=' + orc, function (data1) {
                       
                     var linha2 = ``;
                        for (var i = 0; i < data1.length; i++) { 

                            Id = data1[i][0];
                            DataRegisto = data1[i][1];
                            Cliente = data1[i][2];
                            Orcamento = data1[i][3];
                            Ref = data1[i][4];
                            Designacao = data1[i][5];
                            Quantidade = data1[i][6];
                            Valor = data1[i][7];
                            Compra = data1[i][8];

                            linha2 += `<input type="checkbox" name="eliprod[]" class="rest" value="${ Id }">
                              <input type="hidden" class="form-control1" name="Id[]" value="${Id}">
                              <div class="form-group col-md-2">  
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control1" name="Refe[]" value="${Ref}">
                                    <span class="form-highlight"></span>
                                    <span class="form-bar"></span>
                                    <label class="label1" for="Refe">Refª</label>        
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="form-group col-md-6">  
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control1" name="Designaca[]" value="${Designacao}">
                                    <span class="form-highlight"></span>
                                    <span class="form-bar"></span>
                                    <label class="label1" for="Designaca">Designação</label>        
                                  </div>`;
                            }
                            linha2 += `<button class="btn btn-danger caixa btn-show close-sidebar delete_prod"><i class="fa fa-trash fa-5x taman" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                            $("#retorc1").html(linha2); 
                            }); 
                
                    alert("Produto removido com sucesso");
                    
               }
            });
        }

    });
```

So it works, but it has the problem of updating the form. I wanted to delete the form inputs according to the database without updating the form

Answer (score 0):

First, you will want to wrap the each row of data in a div element, this will be the parent element. Lets call that div, `<div class='item-row'>`.

This will confirm on delete that you want to delete. Then it grabs that parent element.

Since we are only deleting the selected ID, we only need to grab and pass that ID. Then on success we simply remove the `_parent` element from the DOM.

By doing this, the form doesn't change except for the row that you deleted.

```
$(document).on("click", ".delete_prod", function() {
      if (confirm('Tem certeza de que deseja remover o produto do orçamento?')) {
      _parent = $(this).parents(".item-row");
    var dadosajax = {
      "Id[]" : _parent.find("input[name='Id[]']").val(),
    };

        $.ajax({
            url: 'delorc.php',
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            data: dadosajax,
            error: function() {
              alert('Algo está errado!');
            },
            success: function(data) {
               _parent.remove();
            })          
        });
       }
});
```

Comment: The Id variable within dataajax gets this value `1602541505663` and not with the value of `Id`

Comment: @Bruno, try updating the question with the original outputted HTML not the generated HTML within the ajax

Comment: The original htm you have is just the form, because I create the whole form generated dynamically. I can put the complete form if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem as follows:

First I created a parent div as follows with the inputs I want to eliminate:

```
<div id="produto-${ Id }">

...

</div>
```

Then I picked up the IDs of the selected checkboxes as follows:

```
var checados = [];
  $.each($("input[name='eliprod[]']:checked"), function(){            
    checados.push($(this).val());
  });
```

In success I made a loop to eliminate the lines on the form even when I select more than one checkbox like this:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < checados.length; i++) { 
     Id = checados;
     $('#produto-' + Id[i]).remove();
 }
```

Full code:

```
 $(document).on("click", ".delete_prod", function(){

 var checados = [];
  $.each($("input[name='eliprod[]']:checked"), function(){            
      checados.push($(this).val());
  });

    var dadosajax = {
     'checados[]' : checados
    };

    if(confirm('Tem certeza de que deseja remover o produto do orçamento?'))
    {
        $.ajax({
           url: 'delorc.php',
           type: 'GET',
           cache: false,
           data: dadosajax,
           error: function() {
              alert('Algo está errado!');
           },
           success: function(data) {

             for (var i = 0; i < checados.length; i++) { 
                Id = checados;
    
                $('#produto-' + Id[i]).remove();
             }
                alert("Produto removido com sucesso");
                
           }
        });
    }

  });
```